# OBIEE Parameter settings, Select all error

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I have created a parameter Division in OBIEE which is a string and has menu type. When I give the option to select all, by default, null values are passed and hence, the report returns no rows.
I tried using nvl command, "Division" IN (nvl(:division_param, "Division")) which did not work.
Also, I tried to use division<> null in the SQL LOV which did not work. Another option is to use multiple selection and disable select all. But select all option is very important for this report. Please let me know hoe to fix this issue or any work around is appreciated.
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QucUY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the radio button to pass all values instead of null